# Aggregate rolling totals for last 3 months for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, hive

| ID | Date | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202201 | 100 |
| 1 | 202112 | 50 |
| 1 | 202111 | 70 |
| 1 | 202110 | 120 |
| 1 | 202110 | 5 |

Required output: sum of previous 3 months of totals

| ID | Date | Cost | Rolling3Months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202201 | 100 | 220 |
| 1 | 202112 | 50 | 240 |
| 1 | 202111 | 70 | 195 |
| 1 | 202110 | 120 | 125 |
| 1 | 202110 | 5 | 5 |

Required output: sum of previous 3 months of totals

Comment: SQL Server is not the same thing as Hive - please correct your tags. Also questions showing an attempt often get received better.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you do actually want a SQL Server solution:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  ID INT,
  [Date] date, --<< [Date] is a terrible column name & changed the data to be actual dates
  Cost INT
);

INSERT INTO your_table (ID, Date, Cost) VALUES (1, '20220101', 100);
INSERT INTO your_table (ID, Date, Cost) VALUES (1, '20211201', 50);
INSERT INTO your_table (ID, Date, Cost) VALUES (1, '20211101', 70);
INSERT INTO your_table (ID, Date, Cost) VALUES (1, '20211001', 120);
INSERT INTO your_table (ID, Date, Cost) VALUES (1, '20210901', 5); --<< changed to "09"
```

```
5 rows affected
```

```
SELECT ID, Date, Cost, 
       SUM(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Date] ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Rolling3Months
FROM your_table
order by [date] DESC
```

| ID | Date | Cost | Rolling3Months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 100 | 220 |
| 1 | 2021-12-01 | 50 | 240 |
| 1 | 2021-11-01 | 70 | 195 |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 | 120 | 125 |
| 1 | 2021-09-01 | 5 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/K2QZo95n)

the query will also work on the YYYYMM strings you call "Date". See: https://dbfiddle.uk/xbxUsZA6